# How to Authenticate user to my Firebase App specifying the provider (Facebook, Google) with new Firebase 3.2.1 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am updating my iOS app written in Swift(v2.2) to use Firebase 3.2.1. I have updated my code to use the new API to authenticate my user with an email and password to my Firebase App. However, now it looks like I also need to update my code to be able to sign in with Facebook and Google. After the Facebook and Google sign in process is done and the user has been logged in to Facebook or Google, according to the old documentation I also needed to sign in the user to my Firebase app using the following:

```
  // User is signed in to Facebook!
  // Now, authenticate the user to your Firebase app
  let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
  UserService.firebase.BASE_REF.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
       if error != nil {
          //print("An error occurred!")
       } else {
          //print("User signed in!")
       }
```

I have not been able to find a method in the new API that would do something similar to the `authWithOAuthProvider()` method. Please help, thank you!

> Error: Value of type FIRDatabaseReference has no member
>   authWithOAuthProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for Facebook login, I guess it is pretty much the same for Google, just create a proper credential.

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
        // handle logged in user
 }
```